# python extract links from an RSS feed

Tags: python

I am using a URL which is http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2012-02.xml and parsing it with [feedparser-5.1.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) using the command:

`g = feedparser.parse('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2012-02.xml')`

If you go to that URL you will see that **there are many zip files per link in a list**.

My objective is to find and extract all the links for the zip files.

By putting the command: `g['feed']` in python Shell i get the feed.

The [webinar(slide 8)](http://www.slideshare.net/afalk42/xbrl-us-altova-webinar) offers some code for this purpose which i am unable to utilize.

An excerpt i put to this post:

```
for item in feed.entries:
    print( item[ "summary" ], item[ "title" ], item[ "published" ] )
    try:
        # Identify ZIP file enclosure, if available
        enclosures = [ l for l in item[ "links" ] if l[ "rel" ] == "enclosure" ]
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Change name from `g` to `feed` and you will can use this code.

Comment: You are absolutely right! It works! If you put that in an answer i will mark it correct immediately.

Comment: So I add comment as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change name from `g` to `feed` and you will can use this code.